# Tables for Product Components AND Component Combinations

Tags: database-design

I have a basic understanding of relational databases and would like to assign a number of attributes to an assortment of *products*. *Products* examined consistently have four *components*: *model*, *fabric*, *color* and *size*; each of which has a corresponding vendor-supplied *identifier* (ie. 'SSSS.MMMM.CCCC.ZZZZ' = a single *product* at the *size* level).

The most streamlined solution would seem to be having a *product* table that is at the *size* level, then a table for *model*, *fabric*, *color* and *size* to assign relevant attributes under each. The problem I am facing is that I would like to assign certain attributes to, say, a given *fabric/color combination*. Should I then also have tables of each *fabric/color combination* in this case?

I have laid out roughly what I am referring to above with the below table diagram:

[image: Database Diagram]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57763/discussion-on-question-by-user329488-tables-for-product-components-and-component).

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation would be to have a separate table four each of the for attributes listing the different options. This is purely to make it easy to validate data entry.

Then a product for each combination that is required - store transactions against this.

Then a product line table that has several products of different sizes/colors whatever.

Reason for this approach is that a colour/size combination represents a product that should be tracked distinctly from any other size/color of the same thing. A product line might be 'army cargo trousers', and could come in lots of sizes and colours.